# How to list and customize tmux's key bindings applicable for command mode?

Tags: configuration, tmux

Can anyone tell me where to find the official or a comprehensive description of how to list and customize tmux's key bindings applicable for command mode?

When searching for information related to tmux's command mode in its [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) I only find the following elaborations:

> TMUX(1)                  BSD General Commands Manual                TMUX(1)
>
> ...
>
> ```
> status-keys [vi | emacs]
>         Use vi or emacs-style key bindings in the status line, for
>         example at the command prompt.  The default is emacs, unless
>         the VISUAL or EDITOR environment vari‐ ables are set and
>         contain the string ‘vi’.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> The following keys have a special meaning in the command prompt,
> depending on the value of the status-keys option:
>     Function                             vi        emacs
>     Cancel command prompt                Escape    Escape
>     Delete current word                            C-w
>     Delete entire command                d         C-u
>     Delete from cursor to end            D         C-k
>     Execute command                      Enter     Enter
>     Get next command from history                  Down
>     Get previous command from history              Up
>     Insert top paste buffer              p         C-y
>     Look for completions                 Tab       Tab
>     Move cursor left                     h         Left
>     Move cursor right                    l         Right
>     Move cursor to end                   $         C-e
>     Move cursor to next word             w         M-f
>     Move cursor to previous word         b         M-b
>     Move cursor to start                 0         C-a
>     Transpose characters                           C-t
> ```